# Oops!! Method create.en not found for resource chats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apipie

I am using apipie gem for api documentation.
Under my api folder, there is one version**(api/v1)

When I access http://localhost:3000/apipie it shows me the documentation but when clicking on api document url ie `POST /api/chats`

It redirects to  `http://localhost:3000/apipie/public/chats/create.en.html`

It displays error
 `Oops!! Method create.en not found for resource chats.`

But when I remove .en form url manually it displays right api documentation.
ie `http://localhost:3000/apipie/public/chats/create.html`.

I am confusing why api doc redirect to `.en.html` and how I avoid adding `.en` in api doc url.

Comment: how does your `rake routes` looks like? how does that link looks like?

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for help i solve these by creating apipie custom view and comment @doc[:link_extension]  these code in view.

Answer (score 8):

This is an bug which is already reported [here](http://This%20is%20an%20bug%20and%20already%20reported%20[here]%20https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails/issues/565%20%20use%20can%20skip%20this%20translation%20by)

You can fix the problem by adding following line into `apipie.rb` file

```
config.translate = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to translate, you can add the following to apipie.rb file

```
config.translate = false
```

or if you want to translate and if you are using I18n to translate you can simply use

```
config.languages                = %w[en fr] #replace this with list of #locales you use in your app
  config.default_locale           = 'en'
  config.locale                   = lambda { |loc| loc ? I18n.locale = loc : I18n.locale }
  config.translate                = lambda do |str, loc|
    return '' if str.blank?

    I18n.t str, locale: loc, scope: 'doc'
  end
```